# Anaconda conda.compat module warning comes up whenever I install new packages/modules

Tags: anaconda

When I was trying to install packages like html5lib, BeautifulSoup4, sqlalchemy etc. I got the following message prompted in my command line window.

```
Warning: the conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

What does it exactly mean? And what should I do about it?

Comment: See the [answers] on superuser(https://superuser.com/questions/1422008/conda-install-packagename-gives-deprecation-warning)

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug in conda 4.6.11 [github link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8512) which is corrected in latest version of conda 4.6.12.

for more details refer  superuser [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1422008/conda-install-packagename-gives-deprecation-warning) .

Answer (score 2):

[update conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/install-conda-build.html) to latest version and it will start working.

> conda update conda